# I am receiving mail on the mail id which i am entering in input box in laravel 5.7

Tags: email, php-7, smtp

I just make a email form which send mail on my gmail account, but I am receiving mail on the same id which i am entering in input box, Please help me how I will solve this issue.
Here is my controller Code: `ContactController.php`

```
$data=[
'user_email'=>$r->user_email,
'user_name'=>$r->user_name,
'user_phone'=>$r->user_phone,
'user_desc'=>$r->user_desc,
    ];
Mail::send('mail', $data, function($message) use($data)
{
    $message->from('sumitsaini12@gmail.com', 'Email Form Future 
Realty India');
    $message->to($data['user_email']);
    $message->subject($data['user_desc']);
});
return redirect()->back()->with('message','successfully data insertd');
```

}

here is my `.env` file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=sumitsaini12@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=12356
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Here is my view file: `contact.blade.php`

```
<form action="{{url('/postEmail')}}" method="post" class="callus">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="single-query form-group @if($errors->has('user_name')) validate-has-error @endif ">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Your Name" name="user_name" id="user_name" class="keyword-input">
                        @if($errors->has('user_name'))
      <span id="user_name-error" class="validate-has-error">{{ $errors->first('user_name') }}</span>
      @endif
                        </div>
                        <div class="single-query form-group @if($errors->has('user_phone')) validate-has-error @endif ">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" id="user_phone" name="user_phone" class="keyword-input">
                        @if($errors->has('user_phone'))
                        <span id="user_phone-error" class="validate-has-error">{{ $errors->first('user_phone') }}</span>
                        @endif
                      </div>
                      <div class="single-query form-group @if($errors->has('user_email')) validate-has-error @endif">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Email Adress" id="user_email" name="user_email" class="keyword-input">
                        @if($errors->has('user_email'))
                       <span id="user_email-error" class="validate-has-error">{{ $errors->first('user_email') }}</span>
                        @endif
                      </div>
                      <div class="single-query form-group @if($errors->has('user_desc')) validate-has-error @endif">
                        <textarea placeholder="Massege" name="user_desc" id="user_desc" class="form-control"></textarea>
                        @if($errors->has('user_desc'))
                        <span id="user_desc-error" class="validate-has-error">{{ $errors->first('user_desc') }}</span>
                        @endif
                      </div>
                      <input type="submit" value="submit now" class="btn-blue">
                      </div>
                      </form>
```

Here is my: `mail.blade.php`

```
<div class="contact">
<b>User Name:</b>{{$user_name}}<br>
<b>User Mail:</b>{{$user_email}}<br>
<b>User Contact:</b>{{$user_phone}}<br>
<b>User Email:</b> {!! $user_desc !!}<br>
```

Comment: I already use {!! $user_desc !!} in my mail.blade.php file...

Comment: This is an off-topic question. You should ask this on https://laracasts.com/